# ctrl + t and ctrl + f doesn't work any program windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

As the title states. I've tested in sublime text, notepad ++, chrome, firefox, word.

All other keyboard shortcuts seem to work like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>, etc.

I tried removing the keyboard driver, restarting. Any help?

Comment: Check the keycode. http://delphiforfun.org/programs/utilities/KeyCodes.htm

Comment: This is the output when I do ctrl + c then ctrl + v, then ctrl + t then ctrl + f ***OnKeyPress 
OnKeyup, Key code=67, Control keys= Ctrl{Left}, Key name c
OnKeyup, Key code=17, Control keys=, Key name CTRL

OnKeyPress 
OnKeyup, Key code=86, Control keys= Ctrl{Left}, Key name v
OnKeyup, Key code=17, Control keys=, Key name CTRL

OnKeyup, Key code=17, Control keys=, Key name CTRL

OnKeyup, Key code=17, Control keys=, Key name CTRL***

Comment: It appears when control is pressed your machine is not receiving the t or f keys. Have you tried a different keyboard?

Comment: I'll try then as soon as I can. Not sure why t and f would not work with pressing ctrl at the same time though.

Comment: I don't know either, but it's pretty clear from the above. It does sound strange though.

Comment: A special keyboard that may have or has functions bound to `CTRL+t` and `CTRL+f`? A keyboard switcher in use? (https://www.google.se/search?#channel=fs&q=belkin+kvm)

Answer (score 0):

When Ctrl + F did not work in chrome, I followed the pop up and noted that it is FTP Free which I do not use.  I right clicked on the icon for FTP Free and chose to remove it.  I now can use CTRL+F for the "find" command  to search for words on a browser page in Chrome.